# Запятые в стихотворении перед союзом "чтоб"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, инверсия

Помогите, пожалуйста, с запятыми. Правильно ли я расставил их в следующем отрывке? Запятая непосредственно перед "чтоб" не нужна ведь?

> Мне бы прижаться к тебе и обнять,
> Поцелуй на губах чтоб застыл.

Answer (score 1):

*Мне бы прижаться к тебе и обнять,

Поцелуй на губах **чтоб** застыл.*

Этот кусочек стихотворения — сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором имеется союз "чтоб" (равнозначный союзу "чтобы").
Придаточное предложение с таким союзом отделяется от главного запятой (пунктуация у вас правильная: перед собственно "чтоб" запятая, конечно же, уже не нужна).

Особенностью предложения является то, что в нем используется [**инверсия**](https://pishi-stihi.ru/inversiya.html) — "изменение обычного порядка слов... с целью подчёркивания смысловой значимости какого-либо слова или придания всей фразе особой стилистической окрашенности" (то есть нестандартный порядок слов).

> В первую очередь, инверсия меняет интонационный рисунок текста, расставляет иные акценты, нежели при типичной организации речи. Перестановка слов в предложении помогает концентрировать внимания читателя на каких-либо важных деталях и формирует настроение произведения. Инверсия – это эффективное средство создания выразительной, запоминающейся речи.

При прямом порядке слов придаточная часть выглядела бы так: *чтоб поцелуй застыл на губах.*

Вот известнейшие строки с использованием инверсии (В. Высоцкий):
*Очень вырос в целом мире

Гриппа вирус — три-четыре! —

Ширится, растет заболевание.

Если хилый — сразу в гроб!

Сохранить здоровье **чтоб**,

Применяйте, люди, об-

тирания.*

[чтоб; чтобы](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1) (союз)
[Порядок слов в предложении](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/poryadok-slov-v-predlozhenii.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работаю гравёром. Клиенты постоянно спорят со мной. А у этой клиентки ещё и родственница - учительница русского языка. Решил выложить вопрос сюда)

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, Ян! Интересно-интересно, а о чём спорят-то?